# MYSQL: merge column from separate tables

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables with different structures but all share a common column, my tables are: PDF,IMG,FLASH and they all have the columns UNITID and PROJECTID.

Is it possible to query just these columns and merge them?

Comment: what do you mean with merge? Do you know about SQL JOIN?

Comment: have heard but never used it, all the guides on the net I have seen assume your tables are identically structured which is why im wondering if I can apply it to just these two columns from my tables as the rest is not identical.

Comment: of course you can, the only condition is that the joined columns/values are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge the results you will have to use `UNION ALL`

[UNION ALL](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlunionall.html)

Comment: page is in a language I don't understand =/

Comment: @George yeah sorry got the wrong one, updated the link now =)

Comment: Thanks, i actually found the UNION command on there which suits me even better as I was going to make the values unique after :)